# Angular adding String: infront of options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Angular code

```
            $scope.booleans = [ {
                "name" : "True",
                "value" : "true"
            }, {
                "name" : "False",
                "value" : "false",
            } ];
```

HTML

```
<select ng-model="field.insertable" class="form-control" ng-show="editMode"
ng-options="boolean.value as boolean.name for boolean in booleans"></select>
```

Resulting HTML

```
<select ng-model="field.insertable" ng-options="boolean.value as boolean.name for boolean in booleans" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="string:true" label="True">True</option>
        <option value="string:false" label="False">False</option>
 </select>
```

so questions are

- field.insertable has value false coming from backend. How can i set the right value.
- Why option value is `value="string:true"` ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written string values - 'true' and 'false'  , instead write boolean values :

```
 $scope.booleans = [ {
            "name" : "True",
            "value" : true
        }, {
            "name" : "False",
            "value" : false
        } ];
```

Comment: Please write the change in your ans.